# Month Name in Apache Pig Latin

Tags: apache-pig

There must be an easy way to get the month name from a datetime in Pig Latin e.g. 'Jan' for '30/01/2021'? I can't see it documented and haven't turned up the same question anywhere. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `ToString` [function](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/ToString.html).

To customise the format of the string, use the second argument of the function. You can use the [patterns from Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Examples:

For `2021/01/30` use `ToString(datetime_field, 'yyyy/MM/dd')`

For `Jan` use `ToString(datetime_field, 'MMM')`